# Calculate enclosed volume of two meshes

Tags: python, mesh

I am trying  to calculate the enclosed volume of two intersecting meshes.

[image]

From the image above i want to calculate the volume of the solid object that is enclosed by the wireframe cube. Is this a possibility? If so i want to try and get this information using the python API.

Cheers,

Tom